# get real part from fftw_complex in FFTW

Tags: c++, complex-numbers, fftw

this is maybe newbei question , but i dont know how to fast acces to real part of fftw_complex with FFFTW, i cant use .real() method,

I need convert this to double array, dynamic array in c++;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](http://www.fftw.org/doc/Complex-numbers.html), 2 second Google search:

4.1.1 Complex numbers

The default FFTW interface uses double precision for all floating-point numbers, and defines a fftw_complex type to hold complex numbers as:

```
 typedef double fftw_complex[2];
```

Here, **the [0] element holds the real part** and the [1](http://www.fftw.org/doc/Complex-numbers.html) element holds the imaginary part.

Comment: cannot convert 'fftw_complex {aka double [2]}' to 'jdouble {aka double}'